# SQL output to side by side tables

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Outputting variable SQL data to a table.  6 records, which means data is output to 6 separate tables, scrolling down the page.  I'd like to put two record sets in side by side tables, then start a new table row with another dual-set of records, etc., until data WHILE loop is exhausted.  Problem is that I don't know how to access the "Next record" set of data while in the WHILE loop. Would dumping the data into an array be smarter, and then just implement a Next Record from Array counter (N + 1 until record counter = "6" (in this case))?  Please advise.
Code below - works just fine as it is, in a single column of tables.  Not sure if there's a way to output the data in 2 side by side tables, three rows each.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM payroll");
    print "<font size='+1'>Payments made for year <b>" . $payyear . "</b></font><br><br>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
    $username2=$row['username'];

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT fullname, grossytd, taxytd, fedtaxytd, reghoursytd, othoursytd, ficassnytd, ficamedytd, statetaxytd, countytaxytd, netytd FROM payroll WHERE username = '$username2' ORDER BY (counter) DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
     {
    $fullname1 = $row2['fullname'];
    $grossytd1 = number_format($row2['grossytd'], 2);
    $taxytd1 = number_format($row2['taxytd'], 2);
    $fedtaxytd1 = number_format($row2['fedtaxytd'], 2);
    $reghoursytd1 = number_format($row2['reghoursytd'], 2);
    $othoursytd1 = number_format($row2['othoursytd'], 2);
    $ficassnytd1 = number_format($row2['ficassnytd'], 2);
    $ficamedytd1 = number_format($row2['ficamedytd'], 2);
    $statetaxytd1 = number_format($row2['statetaxytd'], 2);
    $countytaxytd1 = number_format($row2['countytaxytd'], 2);
    $netytd1 = number_format($row2['netytd'], 2);

    print "
    <table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr><td align='right'>Employee</td><td align='left' width='140'>" . $fullname1 . "</td> </tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Gross Pay</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $grossytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Taxes Paid</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $taxytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Federal Tax</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $fedtaxytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Regular Hours</td><td align='left' width='140'>" . $reghoursytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Overtime Hours</td><td align='left' width='140'>" . $othoursytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Social Security</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $ficassnytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Medicare</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $ficamedytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>State Taxes</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $statetaxytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>County Taxes</td><td align='left' width='140'>$" . $countytaxytd1 . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td align='right'>Net Pay</td><td align='left' width='100'>$" . $netytd1 . "</td></tr>
    ";
     }
    print "</table>";
    print "<br>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do what you want is to make the tables float.  Add some CSS rules such as the following:

```
table {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

If this doesn't work because of the widths or lengths of your table, then another option is to have a flag that is flipped from true to false on every iteration of the loop.  Then, if the flag is true, store the data for the row in a variable, and if the flag is false, store print out the previously saved data along with the data for the current row.  If you need me to elaborate more on this second approach, please let me know.